# Space Between Carousel Icons - Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, joomla

I've got a Flash carousel on my website, and I've removed one of the icons to have 4 instead of 5. There's meant to be equal space between each icon (images loaded via XML), but there's not.

When I test the movie in Flash (both in Flash and a published SWF), it shows equal space between the 4 icons, but when I embed the same file in my website, the spacing is wrong.

My website address for the carousel is - http://www.myramis.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48&Itemid=54

I'm not sure why the change between a website, and testing the SWF would be different but it is. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. As you can see on the link, there's unnecessary space between the 'Mobile' icon, and the 'Jigsaw' icon.

If you'd like to see my code, let me know I'll copy it here, though there's about 80 lines of code (Actionscript 2).

Edited XML File:

```
<icons>

<icon image="icon3.jpg" tooltip="Ramis Software" link="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=57&Itemid=67"/>

<icon image="icon4.jpg" tooltip="Ramis Lite" link="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=56&Itemid=70"/>

<icon image="icon5.jpg" tooltip="Ramis Mobile" link="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=55&Itemid=71"/>

<icon image="jigsaw.jpg" tooltip="Ramis Modules" link="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=55&Itemid=71"/>

</icons>
```

Hope you can help,

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Comment: Can you post your edited XML file?

Comment: Hi, just posted it in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only deleted the file http://www.myramis.com/images/stories/carousel/icon1.jpg but not its entry in the XML

```
<icon image="images/stories/carousel/icon1.jpg" tooltip="Ramis Assets" link="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=61&Itemid=73" />
```

That's why a blank item is displayed: your carousel puts a placeholder and tries to load an non-existing image into it.

Comment: Hi, I just checked the XML file and it only has 4 items in it, non of which was the item you linked, so how did you inspect the XML file?

Comment: I'm not sure how that is showing, I've checked it a few times and that line doesn't exist in the file at all.

Comment: Well... I couldn't tell :) but still the online version has it.

Comment: You were right, the XML was also in another location, probably because I couldn't get it work in the same folder as the icons, but even though I've modified this as well, its still showing up with the same error, which is very strange.

Comment: have you cleared your browser cache? It might still be loading the old file locally.

Comment: fantastic, its working now, it was a combination of the 2 of your solutions, and it was referencing the wrong xml file location too. Thank you both.